# Laravel Blade Foreach Output

Tags: php, arrays, excel, laravel

I am trying to display the given array, but I cannot seem to get my head around the dimensions of it. I am exporting data from an excel sheet then to an array.

```php
<?php

Excel::selectSheets('active_transport_sheet_1');
$reader->formatdates(true, 'd-m-Y');
$data = $reader->get(array('project_status', 'event_area', 'date_of_event', 'area_to_split', 
    'planned_split', 'actual_staff_on_split_requiring_transport', 'vehicle_type_required', 
    'project_number', 'event_name', 'driver_responsible_person',
    'hire_stauts', 'shift_start_time', 'departure_date', 'departure_time'))
    ->toArray();

$this->data = json_encode($data);
$this->data = json_decode($this->data, true);
```

**Output**

**View**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @foreach ($sheet as $sheets)
        {{$sheets->date_of_event}}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Error**

> "Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wallboards\resources\views\boards\viewexcel.blade.php)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @foreach ($sheet as $sheets)
        {{$sheets->date_of_event}}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

In the above code you are trying to access an object `{{$sheets->date_of_event}}` but its an array. So try `$sheets['date_of_event']`

So the full code is

```
<div class="panel-body">
     @foreach ($sheet as $sheets)
         {{$sheets['date_of_event']}}
     @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that has done the trick. Multi dimensional arrays always throw me off. If I want the name too should I do $sheet as $index => $keys?